# How to add environment variables to Azure Container App

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I cannot find a way to add environment values to `Azure Container App` in the portal.

How can I add within `Azure Portal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Container App is in Preview and currently, not all settings are available in the Portal.  You can use the CLI to add env variables:

```
az containerapp update -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup -v myenvvar=foo,anotherenvvar=bar
```

Refer to the CLI doc:

```
az containerapp --help
```

Comment: What actually worked for me was something like `--set-env-vars "KEY_1=supersecret" "KEY_2=supersecreter"`

Comment: Thanks KTibow, `--set-env-vars` worked.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it also in azure portal:

- Go to Containers
- Click Edit and Deploy:

[image]

- Fill the revision suffix
- Click the container:

[image]

- Edit your env variables as you wish
- You can also reference your secrete here (that you have created in Secretes tab previously)

[image]

- Save the container edit
- Create new revision

Answer (score 8):

Create and update are slightly different...

```
az containerapp create ... \
    --env-vars "FOO_BAR_1=secretref:foo-bar-1" "FOO_BAR_2=$FOO_BAR_2"
```

and

```
az containerapp update ... \
    --set-env-vars "FOO_BAR_2=$FOO_BAR_2"
```

Comment: Gemini and ChatGPT got this mixed as of my writing. Kudos to you